# Can I use Android L switch control theme in android 4.0

Tags: android, mobile, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to know, Can I use Android L switch control theme in android 4.0.
Example please.

Thanks,
AK

Comment: Not unless you create your own custom switch

Comment: Not by using the default Android-L theming, since its still an early developer preview, its not yet compatible with prior versions.

Comment: Also bear in mind that approximately 0% of your users will have seen the "L" implementation of `Switch` and therefore may not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

1. ****1.) Create a new project by File-> New -> Android Project name it SwitchesExample.
   2.) Write following into main.xml:****

   ```
       <Switch android:text="Standard switch"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="32dip" />

       <Switch android:text="Default is on"
               android:checked="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="32dip" />

       <Switch android:id="@+id/monitored_switch"
               android:text="Monitored switch"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginBottom="32dip" />

       <Switch android:text="Customized text"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textOn="Start"
               android:textOff="Stop"
               android:layout_marginBottom="32dip" />       
   </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>
   ```

   3.) Run for output. Steps:
   1.) Create a project named SwitchesExample and set the information as stated in the image. Build Target: Android 4.0 Application Name:
   SwitchesExample Package Name: com. example. SwitchesExample Activity
   Name: SwitchesExample Min SDK Version: 14

   2.) Open SwitchesExample.java file and write following code there: package com.example.SwitchesExample;

   import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import
   android.widget.CompoundButton; import android.widget.Switch; import
   android.widget.Toast;

   public class SwitchesExample extends Activity implements
   CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ```
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.monitored_switch);
       if (s != null) {
           s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Monitored switch is " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } }
   ```

   3 Compile and build the project.